# ArrayList<> get list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi In the code below I have a `LocationManager` with `currentLong` and `currentLat` ,`vars`. On Button click I add `varLat1` and `VarLong1` to the arraylist Coordinates. How do I, using `Log.d` get the values of the array. `marcCoordinates.size()` gives me the correct size but `marcCoordinates.get(s)` gives me `gpsplotter.MainActivity$Coordinates@42204f70` HELP Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  LocationListener {

public class Coordinates {
public final double latitudeX;
public final double longitudeY;
public Coordinates(double lat, double lon) {
    latitudeX = lat;
    longitudeY = lon;}}
```

....

```
 ArrayList<Coordinates> marcCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
```

....

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    varLat1 = (currentLat);
    varLong1 = (currentLong);
marcCoordinates.add(new Coordinates(varLat1, varLong1));
```

...

```
int s =   marcCoordinates.size();
Log.d("log2",""+ marcCoordinates.get(s) + "" +    marcCoordinates.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Coordinates` doesn't have a `toString` method, so the default one of `Object` is used, which is just the name + memory address.

If you want a better representation, override the `toString` method:

```
public class Coordinates {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // return some string here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to mark the question as a duplicate than to create duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString()` method in the class `Coordinates`...

that will solve the issue.

## Example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coordinates [latitude=" + latitude + ", longitud=" + longitud + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `toString()` method your class. Otherwise will be called `toString()` of [Object.class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which doesn't know which properties you would like to expose and will return `ClassName@HashCode`:

```
public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

To fix this just override `toString` in your class:

```
public class Coordinates {
//...
@Override
    public String toString() {
         return "Coordinates [latitude=" + latitude + ", longitud=" + longitud   + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorted :) 
Encountered another problem that I did not foresee. If I want to apply an operator as: double sum = marcCoordinates.get(0) + marcCoordinates.get(1);